# I am trying to extract text using regex but it is not working

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to extract text using regex but it is not working. Although my regex work fine on regex validators.

```
public class HelloWorld {

    public static void main(String []args){

        String PATTERN1 = "F\\{([\\w\\s&]*)\\}";
        String PATTERN2 = "{([\\w\\s&]*)\\}";

        String src = "F{403}#{Title1}";
        List<String> fvalues = Arrays.asList(src.split("#"));

        System.out.println(fieldExtract(fvalues.get(0), PATTERN1));
        System.out.println(fieldExtract(fvalues.get(1), PATTERN2));
   }

   private static String fieldExtract(String src, String ptrn) {
      System.out.println(src);
      System.out.println(ptrn);
      Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(ptrn);
      Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(src);
      return matcher.group(1);
   }
}
```

Comment: which text? is it the Title1 you want to extract?

Comment: I want to extract 403 as well as Title1.

Comment: your patterns are wrong..

Comment: I have validated it here(http://regex101.com/) it is working fine. Is there any issue with escaping?

Comment: Updating String PATTERN2 = "\\{([\\w\\s&]*)\\}".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use:

```
Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("F\\{([\\d\\s&]*)\\}#\\{([\\s\\w&]*)\\}");
```

To get both ?

This way the number will be in group `1` and the title in group `2`.

Another thing if you're going to compile the regex (which can be helpful to performance) at least make the regex object static so that it doesn't get compiled each time you call the function (which kind of misses the whole pre-compilation point :) )

Basic demo [here](http://ideone.com/KoEF8W).

Comment: @vaspaean Glad it does, consider accepting the answer though (that's the `V` sign near it)...

Comment: Sorry, I am new on stack overflow. Thanks again.:)

Answer (score 0):

First problem:

```
String PATTERN2 = "\\{([\\w\\s&]*)\\}"; // quote '{'
```

Second problem:

```
  Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(src);
  if( matcher.matches() ){
      return matcher.group(1);  
  } else ...
```

The Matcher must be asked to plough the field, otherwise you can't harvest the results.

Comment: Well, the missing matches() call was the major problem.

Comment: Actually I was using this, but it seems matcher.matches() doesn't reset the state, which created some issues.

Comment: You don't need a reset if there's just a single match going on. Don't expect a solution presented for the code you post to work in all - possibly completely different - circumstances.